Is it possible to hide pod-mounted kubernetes secrets?
I have the following question, at my work I have secrets stored in a keyvault and I consume them through a secretProviderClass mounted on a pod path.
They ask me if it is possible that when entering the pod and do a cat on the secret, the content is not shown or appears obfuscated
This is the SecretProviderClass to access to key vault
apiVersion: secrets-store.csi.x-k8s.io/v1
kind: SecretProviderClass
metadata:
  name:
  namespace:
spec:
  provider: azure
  parameters:
    usePodIdentity: "false"
    useVMManagedIdentity: "true"
    userAssignedIdentityID:
    keyvaultName:
    cloudName: "AzurePublicCloud" 
    objects:  |
      array:
        - |
          objectName: 
          objectType: secret
          objectVersion: ""
    tenantId: 


Yes, it is possible to hide pod-mounted Kubernetes secrets. You can encrypt the secrets using a tool like HashiCorp Vault, and then decrypt them inside the pod using a sidecar container. This way, the secrets are never stored in plaintext on the node or in the pod and are only accessible to the container that needs them.
Another way to hide the secrets is by using Kubernetes RBAC to restrict access to the secrets. You can create a service account for the pod, and then create a role that only allows that service account to access the secrets. This way, even if someone gains access to the pod, they won't be able to see the secrets unless they have the appropriate permissions.
In below example I am showing you with hashicorp vault
Deploy hashicorp vault to your aks
helm install vault hashicorp/vault --set "server.dev.enabled=true"


Get the unseal keys and root token to unseal and login to the vault
kubectl logs vault-0


 kubectl exec -it vault-0 -- vault login root


Configure Vault to Store Secrets i.e. enable Key Value Secrets Engine and store your Secret in Vault
 kubectl exec -it vault-0 -- vault secrets enable -path=kv kv-v2

 kubectl exec -it vault-0 -- vault kv put kv/my-secret my-secret="whatever-secret-value-you-want-to-put"


Next deploy the vault injector to your aks
helm install vault-injector hashicorp/vault


create your service account , role and role binding
kubectl apply -f - <<EOF
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: vault-auth
  namespace: default
EOF


kubectl apply -f - <<EOF
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: secret-reader
  namespace: default
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["secrets"]
  verbs: ["get"]
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: read-secrets
  namespace: default
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: vault-auth
  namespace: default
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: secret-reader
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
EOF


Configure your aks to Use the Vault by creating a vault policy and vault auth role

kubectl exec -it vault-0 -- vault policy write my-app-policy - <<EOF
path "kv/data/my-secret" {
  capabilities = ["read"]
}
EOF


You need to configure Vault with the Kubernetes API server address and the token reviewer JWT.
SA_SECRET_NAME=$(kubectl get sa vault-auth -o jsonpath='{.secrets[0].name}')
SA_JWT_TOKEN=$(kubectl get secret $SA_SECRET_NAME -o jsonpath='{.data.token}' | base64 --decode)
SA_CA_CRT=$(kubectl get secret $SA_SECRET_NAME -o jsonpath='{.data.ca\.crt}' | base64 --decode)
K8S_HOST=$(kubectl config view --raw --minify --flatten -o jsonpath='{.clusters[0].cluster.server}')

Configure Vault with Kubernetes Auth Method

Now, create the Kubernetes auth role in Vault
 kubectl exec -it vault-0 -- vault write auth/kubernetes/config \
    token_reviewer_jwt="$SA_JWT_TOKEN" \
    kubernetes_host="$K8S_HOST" \
    kubernetes_ca_cert="$SA_CA_CRT"


Finally when you deploy the Application with Vault Sidecar edit your pod yaml, and reference the vault details and secret here-

Once deployed, instead of doing a cat on the secret-
kubectl exec -it my-app -- env | grep MY_SECRET

